# thymeleaf отображение БД

Tags: java, html5, hibernate, thymeleaf

Нужно отобразить все имеющиеся профессии (таблца `profession`) в браузере.
Работала аналогии с примером http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html

Но браузер выбрасывает ошибку

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Exception parsing document: template="profession", line 2 - column 42

Контроллер

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Profession", method = GET)
public String showProfession(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("professions",professionService.getAll());
    return "profession";
}
```

Таблица profession

```
@Entity
@Table(name="profession")
public class Profession {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "Profession_Name")
    private String professionName;

    public Profession(){}

    public Profession(String professionName){
        this.professionName =professionName;
    }

    public Integer getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getProfessionName() {
        return professionName;
    }

    public void setProfessionName(String professionName) {
        this.professionName = professionName;
    }

     /*Много(Subject)- ко Многим(Profession) */
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST},mappedBy = "professions")
    private Set<Subject> subjects;

    public Set<Subject> getSubjects() {
        return subjects;
    }

    public void setSubjects(Set<Subject> subjects) {
        this.subjects = subjects;
    }
}
```

ProfessionServiceImpl

```
@Service

public class
 ProfessionServiceImpl implements ProfessionService {
    private final ProfessionRepository repository;
@Autowired
ProfessionServiceImpl(ProfessionRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Override
public List<Profession> getAll() {
    List<Profession> todoEntries = repository.findAll();
    return todoEntries;
}
```

ProfessionService

```
public interface ProfessionService {
     List<Profession> getAll();
}
```

Конфигурация thymeleaf

```
 @Configuration
@EnableWebMvc 
@ComponentScan("ru.matveeva.springmvc")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Bean//настройка view resolver
public ViewResolver viewResolver(SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine) {
    ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
    return viewResolver;
}//Configure a Thymeleaf view resolver

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(TemplateResolver templateResolver) {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
public TemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    TemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    return templateResolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

}

Отображение на страничке (Все профессии)
thymeleaf

```html
<html xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Profession</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/resources/newstyle.css}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/resources/newbootstrap.css}" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>

<body id="pageBody" style="zoom :1;">

  <div class="templatemo-top-bar" id="templatemo-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="subheader">
        <div id="phone" class="pull-left">
          <img th:src="@{/resources//image/phone.png}" alt="phone" />010-020-0340
        </div>
        <div id="email" class="pull-right">
          <img th:src="@{/resources/image/email.png}" alt="email" />contact@website.com
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="top-menu stuckMenu" style="top:0px;position: relative;">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Static navbar -->
      <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
              <img th:src="@{/resources/image/spring.gif}" alt="Spring" title="Spring Project" />
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--/.container-fluid -->
      </div>
      <!--/.navbar -->
    </div>
    <!-- /container -->
  </div>
  <div id="contentOuterSeparator"></div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="divPanel page-content">
      <div class="breadcrumbs">
        <a href="/">Home</a>
        &nbsp;/&nbsp;
        <span>Profession</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="listTitle">
      <h1>Profession</h1>
      <ul class="List">
        <li th:each="profession : ${professions}" th:text="${profession.ProfessionName}">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Что находится на `line 2 - column 42`? Также, неплохо бы увидеть как вы Thymeleaf сконфигурировали.

Comment: @enzo Добавила конфигурацию thymeleaf. И полный документ (html).По поводу ошибки, я так понимаю, он ругается на `<ul class="List">
        <li th:each="profession : ${professions}" th:text="${profession.ProfessionName}">
        </li>`   НО я не уверена. Не понимаю, где искать line2-colum42 в (html)

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка была в файле html

Нужно было удалить xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org